# K means Analysis on KDD Cup Dataset 99

Tags: matlab, plot, machine-learning, k-means

What kind of knowledge/ inference can be made from k means clustering analysis of KDDcup99 dataset?

We ploted some graphs using matlab  they looks like this:::

Experiment 1: Plot of dst_host_count vs serror_rate

[image: dst_host_count vs serror_rate]

Experiment 2: Plot of srv_count vs srv_serror_rate

[image: srv_count vs srv_serror_rate]

Experiment 3: Plot of count vs serror_rate

[image: count vs serror_rate]

I just extracted saome features from kddcup data set and ploted them.....

The main problem am facing is due to lack of domain knowledge I cant determine what inference can be drawn form this graphs another one is if I have chosen wrong axis then what should be the correct chosen feature?

I got very less time to complete this thing so I don't understand the backgrounds very well
Any help telling the interpretation of these graphs would be helpful

What kind of unsupervised learning can be made using this data and plots?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some domain knowledge: the [KDD cup data set](https://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup99.html) contains information about different aspects of network connections. Each sample contains 'connection duration', 'protocol used', 'source/destination byte size' and many other features that describes one connection connection. Now, some of these connections are malicious. The malicious samples have their unique 'fingerprint' (unique combination of different feature values) that separates them from good ones.

> What kind of knowledge/ inference can be made from k means clustering analysis of KDDcup99 dataset?

You can try k-means clustering to initially cluster the normal and bad connections. Also, the bad connections falls into 4 main categories themselves. So, you can try k = 5, where one cluster will capture the good ones and other 4 the 4 malicious ones. Look at the first section of the [tasks page](https://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/task.html) for details.

You can also check if some dimensions in your data set have high correlation. If so, then you can use something like PCA to reduce some dimensions. Look at the [full list of features](https://kdd.ics.uci.edu/databases/kddcup99/kddcup.names). After PCA, your data will have a simpler representation (with less number of dimensions) and might give better performance.

> What should be the correct chosen feature?

This is hard to tell. Currently data is very high dimensional, so I don't think trying to visualize 2/3 of the dimensions in a graph will give you a good heuristics on what dimensions to choose. I would suggest

- Use all the dimensions for for training and testing the model. This will give you a measure of the best performance.
- Then try removing one dimension at a time to see how much the performance is affected. For example, you remove the dimension 'srv_serror_rate' from your data and the model performance comes out to be almost the same. Then you know this dimension is not giving you any important info about the problem at hand.
- Repeat step two until you can't find any dimension that can be removed without hurting performance.

Comment: Even though its very late to add this comment I would definitely like to thank you for your views which helped me on this  in 2014.Later I visualized that data using all attributes and used cluto toolkit which primarily did the job and later I analyzed them. Extremely sorry for being so late